# Can't install Tensorflow 2.3 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, raspberry-pi, tensorflow2.0

I can't currently install TensorFlow 2.3 on a Raspberry Pi 4.
Unfortunately, the pip doesn't return any TensorFlow version:

```
pip install tensorflow==
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==
```

I read somewhere that TensorFlow only supports the 64-bit version of Python and only the versions between 3.5 to 3.8 so I made sure that I have these versions installed as well.

The current Linux distro that I have is the following `aarch64`.

`pip` and `python` have the following versions:

```
pip -V python
pip 20.3.1 from /home/pi/envs/awe/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

python -V
Python 3.7.3
```

And I also have a 64-bit version of Python:

```
platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'ELF')
```

Why can't pip find a compatible TensorFlow of version 2.3?

Comment: Because there are no prebuilt wheels for the `aarch64` platform tag. You have to build Tensorflow 2 from source.

Comment: I've seen unofficial TF2 wheels for `aarch64` here and there, but didn't try them out; check out [here](https://github.com/bitsy-ai/tensorflow-arm-bin), for example. Use at your own risk, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your replies @hoefling!  Is there any prebuilt wheels for any platform that could work on Raspberry 4? I need TensorFlow 2.3 on it and it wouldn't be any big of a deal on which platform is running.

Comment: I see version 1.14 at https://www.piwheels.org/project/tensorflow/; see https://www.piwheels.org/faq.html

Comment: @UrmLmn there are no wheels prebuilt specifically for a particular Raspberry Pi model; rather you have to check your architecture (that is obviously ARM) and bitness (this depends on your OS; although RPi4 has a 64bit CPU, Raspbian itself is still 32bit etc). For ARM 32bit, use wheel with tag `linux-armv7l`; for 64bit ARM, this would be `linux-aarch64`. Both wheels can be found in the repo I posted above.

Comment: @hoefling So when [the Install page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) says that pre-built packages are available for the Raspberry, that means 32-bit only?

Comment: @unwind if you mean specifically the _tested and supported on the following 64-bit systems: Raspbian 9_ part, I find it pretty much contradictory per se, to start with. The installation guide also seems to be dated at least for RPi ([packages listed for armv6l / Python 3.5 only which has reached EOL?](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location)).

Comment: @unwind the most reliable artifacts source is IMO the project's readme (see [Continuous build status](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#continuous-build-status), which lists `armv6l`/`armv7l` artifacts for the legacy 1.X version, but neither 2.X nor `aarch64`. The list of community builds contains artifacts for `aarch64` and Python 3.6/3.7, but no 3.8 so far. For me, this doesn't sound like _tested and supported_ yet.

Answer (score 2):

For the Raspberry Pi 4 ARM64 platform TensorFlow is not available as pre-built version for pip and must be compiled manually.
Follow these [instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/build/tree/master/raspberry_pi_builds) and cross compile it on a different more powerful environment, not on the Pi 4. The instructions are not up to date anymore, I have completed them here. These are the steps to cross compile TensorFlow 2.3.1 on an Ubuntu Linux:

```sh
git clone git@github.com:tensorflow/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow
```

The old version 2.3.1 does not know Python 3.8. When using Python 3.7 then this might not be necessary.

```sh
wget https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/Dockerfile.pi-python38 -o tensorflow/tools/ci_build/Dockerfile.pi-python38
```

CMake is now also required, I'm using here the master branch, which is corresponding to version 2.5.0 (in case this does not work anymore in the future with the master version):

```sh
wget -O tensorflow/tools/ci_build/install/install_cmake.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/install/install_cmake.sh
chmod +x tensorflow/tools/ci_build/install/install_cmake.sh
```

To support Python 3.8 add support for it, again taken from the master branch (version 2.5.0):

```sh
wget -O tensorflow/tools/ci_build/install/install_pi_python3x_toolchain.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/install/install_pi_python3x_toolchain.sh
chmod +x tensorflow/tools/ci_build/install/install_pi_python3x_toolchain.sh
```

You also need these files for the build:

```sh
wget -O tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh
chmod +x tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh
```

There is an issue with newer `numpy` version. Use this cherry-pick from git:

```sh
git cherry-pick 75ea0b31477d6ba9e990e296bbbd8ca4e7eebadf
```

Now finally all can be compiled. This takes several hours most likely.

```sh
tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh PI-PYTHON38 tensorflow/tools/ci_build/pi/build_raspberry_pi.sh AARCH64
```

If something fails and some files have to be patched or added keep in mind to clean the Docker container to prevent using the Docker cache when restarting the build process. `docker images`, `docker rmi <imageid>` and `docker rm <container>` are your friends.